# List categories in footer in every view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to have my categories in the footer on any template I include my footer in. I have a `Category` model and currently how I'm doing this is to import all category objects through my context. Obviously this is pretty redundant.

**views.py**

```
def homepage_view(request):
    context = {
        "categories": Category.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request=request,
                  template_name='main/index.html', context=context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

### 1. Use a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext)

I think this one would be the most straight-forward solution for you. This will include your category list available in the context object for all your requests. You just need to add your context processor in the app settings:

```
'context_processors': [
          'django.template.context_processors.debug',
          'django.template.context_processors.request',
          'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
          'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
          'myapp.context_processors.include_categories', 
  ],
```

And then define that context processor so it returns your categories:

```
def include_categories(request):
    return {'categories': Category.objects.all()}
```

### 2. Use [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/)

Instead of function-based ones, and create a mixin that includes the categories in the context. It would look something like:

```
class IncludeCategoriesMixin(object):
 """
 A mixin to add the categories to the view context
 """
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["categories"]: Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

Then, in any class-based view you want to include the categories, you will just have to include the mixin class in the view definition:

```
class MyView(TemplateView, IncludeCategoriesMixin):
    ...
```

Check the documentation first to know more for both approaches, but I think this are the simplest solutions you can use to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am getting `No module named 'main.context_processors'` Am I putting the include_categories function in my main/views.py file?

Comment: You have to write the module structure where it should be found. So, in my example it would be under `myapp/context_processors.py`. I think is not mandatory to put it in that separate file, but I like to have a different file for the app context processors for clarity. Hope it helps!